# `Exceeded maximum execution time` error while running Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having trouble in running my Google Apps Scripts. Scripts that were running properly have stopped with the error "Exceeded maximum execution time".

It is not the complexity of the scripts, even some simple scripts I tested won't run.  For example this one times out:

```
function testfunction() {

  var test = 1
  var test = 2
  var test = 3
}
```

Comment: `testfunction` works.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum script runtime is 6 minutes.
All information are available here :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas

You can check all your quotas here :
https://script.google.com/dashboard

if yours scripts wre running properly and now don't, maybe you reach a limit ;);